# vscode, how to format markdown file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems `vscode` does not support format markdown file by default.

When I use the shortcut `command + shift + f` to format the markdown file.

`vscode` give me: `Sorry, but there is no formatter for 'markdown'-files installed.`

Is there a way to format a markdown file without installing an extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, and there is no open issue requesting that too.

You could **try** the [Tidy Markdown Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tehnix.vscode-tidymarkdown) extension, and see if it fit your needs, or just **open an issue** in VS Code repo. Maybe there are plans to do so.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS, you can do with `option` + `shift` + `F` now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following extension:
[Markdown-Formatter by Mervin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mervin.markdown-formatter).

I found this to work better than [Tidy Markdown Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tehnix.vscode-tidymarkdown), especially with code-blocks

Comment: As of v0.9.6 "markdown-formatter" adds extra ending spaces to lines, removes a line break after the top heading, substitutes consistent dash in lists for stars. In one word, I uninstalled it after 5 the first use.

Answer (score -4):

Markdown preview is an out-of-the-box feature of VS Code.

On Windows try pressing Ctrl+Shift+V or Ctrl+K V

(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview)

If that doesnt solve your problem, try [Markdown All-in_one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one). It has been enjoying a bit of popularity.
I use it myself when I need to write mathematical formulas on a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: The question is about markdown formatting, not previewing.